# object as property mongoose mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need a property in a mongoose model that is as following:

**customRanks** should have different keys and different values for each key

```
const config = new Schema({
  id: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
 //...other property 
  customRanks: Object,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can defined `custome rank schema` and use this as a object if you want to save data in **specific format** for **customRanks** fields

```
const customRanksSchema = new Schema({
  key1: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  key2: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  key3: { type: String, default: '' }
})
```

If you want static schema and have specific fields for your custome rank object

```
// if you want to save customeRanks as array of object
customRanks: [{ type: customRanksSchema }],
// if you want to save custom rank as a object
customRanks: customRanksSchema
```

If you are looking for validation **without key** specifically. Then you may need to **validate data before insert/create/update** using javascript.

Comment: yeah but in this way I can't add dynamic element to customRanks

Comment: I need an object property because I need to add certain elements, at the beginning the object is empty

Comment: the closest solution could be maps https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#maps

Comment: @Gianmarco sir if you need dynamic field then your quetion is right  ```customRanks: { type: Object, default: {} }``` you can add many fields. without care of fields.